# How to measure Lake water surface temperature in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, lakes

I need to calculate LSWT from MODIS in Google Earth Engine.

I tried to do my task with SST band of "NOAA AVHRR Pathfinder Version 5.3 Collated Global 4km Sea Surface Temperature" because my study area is Urmia Lake which is a large water body. but I think MODIS will be good.

Here is my code for NOAA:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/81a62ae32c3401f26ce2c176f3a385da

Comment: I suggest you share your prior research and attempts at the task with us. Please make sure to include code if relevant.

Comment: here is my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/81a62ae32c3401f26ce2c176f3a385da

Comment: Please add relevant info to your question, not the comments. Include code not as link.

Comment: Its not possible to access that code - Seems GEE is not publicly accessible. As Eric said - posting your code in this post (use the text formatting guide) would help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this image collection instead :

`var LSWT = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A1')`

It refers to this dataset: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MYD11A1

Make also sure to change the bands names: replace the `sea_surface_temperature` by `LST_Day_1km`.

Note that this dataset returns values in Kelvin with a 0.02 scale meaning that you have to multiply the values by 0.02 to have them in Kelvin (and remove 273.15 if you want in Celcius).